# Slick upserting doesn't work for model which contains ID as character PK (in postgres only)

Tags: postgresql, scala, jdbc, slick, slick-3.0

I try to use `insertOrUpdate` method from the slick framework. And this method works only if my model contains ID as Long autoincrement PK. If I try to use model with ID as unique String PK then the `unsertOrUpdate` method doesn't work in the postgres. But it work in H2.

Environment: `scala-2.11.8`, `slick-3.0.0` or `slick-3.2.1`.

Jdbc drivers: `"org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.4.1211.jre7"` or `"42.1.4"`

Test case with using model which contains ID as String PK:

```
// model and schema
case class Supplier(id: String, name: String)
class Suppliers(tag: Tag) extends Table[Supplier](tag, "suppliers") {
  def id = column[String]("SUP_ID", O.PrimaryKey)
  def name = column[String]("SUP_NAME")
  def * = (id, name) <> (Supplier.tupled, Supplier.unapply)
}

val suppliers = TableQuery[Suppliers]
...

// usage
val action = suppliers.insertOrUpdate(Supplier("2", "name1"))
db.run(action) // raises the following exception (see below)
```

Exception:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "merge"
  Position: 1
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2477)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2190)
    ...
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at slick.jdbc.JdbcActionComponent$InsertActionComposerImpl$InsertOrUpdateAction$$anonfun$nativeUpsert$1.apply(JdbcActionComponent.scala:562)
    at slick.jdbc.JdbcActionComponent$InsertActionComposerImpl$InsertOrUpdateAction$$anonfun$nativeUpsert$1.apply(JdbcActionComponent.scala:559)
    at slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$SessionDef$class.withPreparedStatement(JdbcBackend.scala:371)
```

The above code works correctly with using H2-driver. But doesn't work with using postgresql driver.
Is this a bug or should I use a workaround instead `insertOrUpdate`?

UPD: probably, this issue is cause for [the another problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46096773)

Comment: According to http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.2.1/supported-databases.html `insertOrUpdate` is only supported for MySQL (it might just work for H2 by accident)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel thanks!